# Proof that a series converges to zero

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, covariance, time-series, absolute-convergence

I am working on the following problem arising in time series analysis.

Let us assume that $\sum_{h \in \mathbb{Z}} |\gamma(h)|<\infty$. I would like to prove that
\begin{equation*}
1) \; \; \; \lim_{n\to +\infty} \sum_{h >n } \gamma(h) = 0
\end{equation*}
and the stronger result
\begin{equation*}
2) \; \; \; \lim_{n\to +\infty} \sqrt{n}\sum_{h >n } \gamma(h) = 0
\end{equation*}

I was able to prove 1) using the limit of the partial sum $S_n = \sum_{h=-\infty}^n\gamma(h)$, and then writing $\sum_{h > n} \gamma(h) = \sum_{h \in \mathbb{Z}} \gamma(h) - \sum_{h = -\infty}^{n} \gamma(h) \
$ and taking the limit.
However, for the second question I think I need additional assumptions on the sequence $(\gamma(h))$ in order to prove it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What’s your attempts?

Comment: I was able to prove 1) using the limit of the partial sum $S_n = \sum_{h=-\infty}^n\gamma(h)$, and then writing $\sum_{h > n} \gamma(h) = \sum_{h \in \mathbb{Z}} \gamma(h) - \sum_{h = -\infty}^{n} \gamma(h) \
$ and taking the limit.
However, for the second question I think I need additional assumptions on the sequence $\gamma(h)$ in order to prove it.

Comment: please edit the post adding your effort

Comment: Hint: 2) is wrong without further conditions.

Comment: Consider a decreasing sequence $a_n \to 0$, and define $\gamma(\pm n) = a_{n-1}-a_n$. Then $\sum_{h > n} \gamma(h) = a_n \to 0$. (2) would imply that $\lim_n a_n\sqrt n = 0$ also. Can you think of a decreasing sequence $\{a_n\}$ converging to $0$ such that $a_n\sqrt n$ does not converge to $0$?

Answer (score 1):

The example given by Paul Sinclair give a good path, but one has to be sure that $a_{n-1}-a_n$ gives indeed the covariance function of a stationary sequence.

To do so, take
$X_t=\sum_{i\in\mathbb Z}a_i\varepsilon_{t-i}$, where $(\varepsilon_k)$ is i.i.d., centered and has unit variance, $a_i> 0$, $\sum_{i\in\mathbb Z}a_i<\infty$ and $\sqrt{N}\sum_{i>N}a_i\geqslant 1$. Then
$$
\gamma(h)=\mathbb E[X_0X_h]=\sum_{i\in\mathbb Z}a_{h+i}a_i
$$
hence $\sum_{h\in\mathbb Z}\gamma(h)<\infty$ and
$\gamma(h)\geqslant a_0a_h$.